# Maintaining the Back Stack between Activities

Tags: android, back-stack

My Problem is suppose we have 4 activites.

> A->B->C->D

.
In Activity C, I pass an intent to go to D and from D it again comes back to C.After getting the required result from D in C,I run an Async Task after which I have to come back to B.Now when I BackPress at B instead of going to A,the activity changes to

> B->C->B->A.

This could surely be a duplicate question but am not getting the correct answer to my question.

Comment: please show your code from navigating to Activity A going to Activity D, and also, did you handle the backpress?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to maintain the previous state of an activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9147981/how-to-maintain-the-previous-state-of-an-activity)

Comment: maybe post code from activity B so the problem can be clarified.

Comment: I have been using normal Intent calls with finish(); to navigate between activities.
From B to C ->  env_edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Renovate1.this, Environment.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

            }
        });

Comment: To explain the work flow.
Activity B has different views for images.
On pressing some button in B we go to C where images are captured (gallery/camera).The images are further taken to D where user can edit the image.On button click, this image is taken back to C.At Activity C,am doing some work at onBackPressed(); where user has to make some decision.Whatver decision he makes,the activity comes back to B.Now when i click back button at B it again takes me C instead of A

Answer (score 0):

Store this context of activities B,C,D in a static variable like this

Activity C

```
private static C cContext; 
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_c);
        cContext=this;
}
```

Do same thing on Activity D also and in Activity B

```
private static B bContext; 
     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_b);
            clearAllTasks();
            bContext=this;
    }
 private void clearAllTasks() {
        if(D.dContext!=null)
            D.dContext.finish();
        if(C.cContext!=null)
            C.cContext.finish();
        if(B.bContext!=null)
            B.bContext.finish();
    }
```

Like this you can clear your backstack.From Activity B it will finish all other activies.

If you are coming to Activity B without calling intent from Activity C or D you can call `clearAllTasks();` in `onResume()`.

Comment: Nope,Still not happening.
B->C->D->C
This flow is working fine.
But when i use intent and finish() from C to goto B and then backpress at B it again takes me to C.Moreover C is also at the initial state,not the updated one

Comment: Try to call clearAllTasks() in both onCreate() and onResume()

Comment: On Debugging,Its going under clearAllTasks() at Class B.But then it again goes back to Class C.From C, on backpress it goes to Class B and from there the method seems to work as from there it goes to Class A.

Comment: Check finish() methods of B,D and C also executing in clearAllTasks() when debugging

Comment: well adding the following Flag helped me in overcoming the problem:

  Intent intent = new Intent(Environment.this, Renovate.class);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish(); 

Thanks @Jinesh for the help