# Moving back, then forward to a previous activity: How to maintain contents of editText fields

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I've found what looks like the answer to this here - [How to maintain the previous state of an activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9147981/how-to-maintain-the-previous-state-of-an-activity) - but I'm looking for a solution which works using OnClickListener code. The code I'm currently using to call Activities is:

```
NextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
   startActivity(new Intent(GroupRegistrationStep2.this, GroupRegistrationStep3.class));

        }

    });
```

Here's what I'm doing. The user is taken through four different screens where they input group data, and they can go back or forward as they enter it. I'm using onBackPressed() to handle going back, but when a user enters some data on a screen (say screen 2), goes back to screen 1 to check something, and then hits Next to return to 2, any data they entered into the fields has gone.

I'd like a way of calling the activity but have it retain the data entered in the editText fields/selected in the spinners, etc.

Can anyone help? I've done a lot of VB.net coding in the past but am new to Java and Android Studio so would appreciate a solution for dummies. If someone could let me know what my code above should be to make this work, plus any other changes I'd need to make, that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to create a multiple paged form. Instead of launching new activities for different forms, try using a single activity with multiple fragments and place it in a viewpager. That way you can place "next" and "back" buttons to navigate between the viewpager' fragment and still retaining values within the activity.

If you really like to work with separate activities, you can save key-value pairs temporarily to SharedPreferences. You can achieve this using the code snippet below.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString("FieldName", "Put the value of the field here");
editor.commit();
```

Then you can retrieve the value by:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String value = sharedPref.getString("FieldName", "");
// Now place this value to the activity's field
```

Be sure to clear the necessary preferences if you have successfully completed the form.

Comment: Thanks for that. I was looking at fragments as one way of doing this, but have already built many of the screens and set up the code, so if possible would rather find a solution that works with separate Activities. But if I can't get this to work, your solution would be my Plan B.

Comment: Please see my edited solution to answer this problem.